# Should a question be immediately clear, or require more careful reading

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11308214 which I voted to close as `Unclear what you're asking` as in my initial reading of the question I was not sure exactly what the poster was asking for.

After failing the review I read the question much more in-depth and realized that with some thought and careful reading, the poster was asking a question correctly but had poorly formatted their paragraphs.

While I'll take the audit failure on the chin, I went ahead and edited the question to make it much clearer.

This brings me to my question: is it reasonable to vote as 'unclear what you're asking' when the question may be there, but is poorly written or formatted? Or is it on me as a reviewer to be much more thorough in my review of questions? (or both?)

For completeness, the question as it appeared when I reviewed it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35221022/1

Edit:

This is a different question to the duplicate. That is asking how long you should wait until you close for being unclear. I'm asking that once a question is in the low quality queue how in-depth one should read to try and understand the question before voting to close. Once it's in the review queue, you could reasonably assume other people have thought it's a bad question.

Comment: The English isn't great, but it's pretty clear to me what the question is asking from just a quick read of it.  It could use some editing, but I see no reason to it to need to be closed.  It's not unanswerable in it's original state.  A lower quality question, perhaps, but "unanswerable", no.

Comment: Clarity is somewhat subjective. A question can be immediately clear either to someone who can (or has the patience to) decipher its poor language but not someone who can't, or, in the case of a well-written expert question, to an expert on the subject matter but not to someone unfamiliar with the subject matter. I would consider this borderline in terms of writing - I've seen much worse.

Comment: @BoltClock I agree. I guess my question comes down to how much effort is expected to decipher a question that's already in the review queue where one could assume other people already think it's low quality? I suppose there's always the `Skip` button if you're not sure.

Comment: @Servy perhaps I misunderstand the point of that particular close reason, but wouldn't a question being closed an "unclear" indicate editing is required anyway?

Comment: @Steve An "unclear" question needs significant editing *to become answerable*.  But not all posts that could use some amount of editing are necessarily unclear.  Some posts could use some editing but are still answerable without it.

Comment: @gnat I don't think this is a duplicate, I'm asking specifically about reviewing a low quality question to close, rather than asking the poster directly for edits.

Comment: It is a task, not a question.

Comment: I think you're trying to overgeneralize this question, starting with the title. It confused 5 people into closing your question as a duplicate.